# Select MySqli OO with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

How can a *SELECT* statement be run with MySqli OO using prepared statements?

I am trying to learn and I could do the *INSERT*, *DELETE*, and *UPDATE* statements, but I have problems with *SELECT*. I have been searching but I still do not understand *SELECT* with prepared statements (read the [PHP man page for prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).

Without prepared statements, it works well:

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM test
        WHERE id = 2";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["title"] . "<br>";
    }

    $conn->close();
```

#### With prepared statements:

What I tried does not work.
I think I have problems with showing the data in this case. Can someone explain it please?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT title 
                        FROM test 
                        WHERE id = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$id = 18;
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row["title"] . "<br>";
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$id = 18;` invert these. You're putting the horse before the wagon here,  *as it were*.

Comment: I have put $id on top but it still does not show anything

Comment: that was just part of the error you made

Comment: @Jay, Fred the answer of Your Common Sense works well and puts $id after. Can you explain?

Comment: Sure it works and I can explain it, but he's the one who should be doing that, not us/me.

Comment: My bad. Apparently `execute()` takes care of the parameter binding regardless of the order in the code.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not your bad; it just makes perfect logical sense and I don't know why you deleted your comment. I kept my comment up there for a reason. Had that execute failed, so would the variable and throw an undefined variable notice.

Comment: @segon that's the "after sales service" you get from "the Great One" which wasn't "great", now was it? He's ignoring you and me too. Unless...... he doesn't know and he is unable to offer you an explanation. Or, that he wants you to figure it out by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes me wonder why you weren't able make it [to the end of example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php#example-1788) and started devising a syntax of your own. What do you think `bind_result($title)` is for? And where did you get `$row` from?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT title FROM test WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$id = 18;
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $title . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: The comments above says that $id should go before bind param. What do you think about that? In fact your code works with $id after.

Comment: [Care to answer the OP?...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551469/select-mysqli-oo-with-prepared-statements#comment70308595_41551469). There is a perfectly logical explanation for it. This is on a "OP need to know" basis.